# Run all programs file whose same name by batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have a folder which contains many sub-folders, each this sub-folder contains a program file named bk.bat in its root.

I want to write a bat file so that I can execute all these bk.bat files.
Please help.

Mine is [folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6yg3L.png)

Comment: Please share what you've tried so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a batch file in your WWW folder and put this code in it.

```
FOR /F "delims=" %%G IN ('dir /a-d /b /s bk.bat') DO CALL "%%~G"
```

Comment: Sorry but it says   '%%G was unexpected at this time.'

Comment: Are you running this line of code in command prompt directly? if so, replace the `%%`s by `%` each...

Comment: Ah, it is because I run directly. Create a bat file in www works

Comment: @trang Well I did specifically say create a batch file in your WWW folder!